# GameService without GameComponent?

Tags: .net, xna

In XNA, is it acceptable to create a `GameService` for an object that isn't a `GameComponent`? I know that a `GameService` is intended to be a way to access a `GameComponent`, but what if the object that you're trying to provide access to doesn't need to update on every update cycle? For example, I have a `Camera2D` object that can calculate a `Matrix` for `SpriteBatch.Begin()`. The camera doesn't need to update itself, as it's position, rotation, etc., are updated by the game code.

All that you need to create a `GameService` is a type and a provider object, so the provider object doesn't have to extend `GameComponent`, but is this an acceptable way of doing things? Is there a better way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get this Camera2D class?

Comment: I wrote it myself, based on some of the links from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712296/xna-2d-camera-engine-that-follows-sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services don't have to also be a GameComponent. Just have a look at [GraphicsDeviceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.aspx), it provides the IGraphicsDeviceService and is not a GameComponent. The game services container is just a way of loosely coupling your objects.

Create an interface ICamera2D, make your Camera2D class implement it, and then register an instance of Camera2D as the service provider for ICamera2D in Game.Services. You then use that interface to communicate with the Camera2D instance in your other classes. This means that if at some point you have to change to OtherCamera2D, you only have to register it instead of an instance of Camera2D in your services container and do not have to modify your other classes.